# How to set width and background color of the cell while exporting to excel with multiple sheets in using ExcelHelper class

Tags: asp.net, excel

I could create multiple sheets in an excel file
But I could not format the cells by giving proper width to the columns

I need to display the generated excel like:-

```
  column1                                               column2
```

dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaiaaaaaaa                           4
data data ggghjkkllil

aaaaaddfdfffgggggggggggggg                               5

column1 and column2 should be centrally aligned while column column1
and column2  data should be wrapper text with blue color as background

this requires the columns to give proper width and text should be
wrapper text.Unfortunately i am unable to do give the proper
styles.And also i want to apply background color to the cell.For background color i am using

```
sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior ss:Color=""#2E2EFE""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
```

But its nt working. here i am  giving my code.

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(818);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"<?mso-application progid=""Excel.Sheet""?>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"<Workbook xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:o=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:ss=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet""{0}", Environment.NewLine);

    sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:html=""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@" <Styles>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""Default"" ss:Name=""Normal"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Alignment ss:Vertical=""Bottom""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Borders/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#000000""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <NumberFormat/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Protection/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);


    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s62"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Alignment ss:Vertical=""Bottom""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""14"" ss:Color=""#000000""{0} ", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"    ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);

    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);

    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s65"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);       
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <ss:Borders>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <ss:Border ss:Position=""Bottom"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1"" />{0}",Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <ss:Border ss:Position=""Top"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1"" />{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <ss:Border ss:Position=""Left"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1"" />{0}",Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <ss:Border ss:Position=""Right"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1"" />{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   </ss:Borders>{0}", Environment.NewLine);      
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""12"" ss:Color=""#2E2EFE""{0} ", Environment.NewLine);       
    sb.AppendFormat(@"    ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);       
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);


    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s63"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <NumberFormat ss:Format=""Short Date""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@" </Styles>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(@"{0}\r\n</Workbook>");
    return sb.ToString();
```

Can you help me to do so..

Answer (score 2):

I think its too late maybe you already got solution for this. But still i am giving solution which is working fine for me.

For adding Background use below code:-

```
        sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""backgroundYellow"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);

        sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior  ss:Color= ""#008000"" ss:Pattern=""Solid"" />{0}", Environment.NewLine);

        sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
```

You have missed the tag **ss:Pattern=""Solid""**